# Can a paired/bonded bluetooth device wake an Oreo or higher Android device

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, pairing

I have a security system where moving a Bluetooth LE device causes my android application to do some work. After some of the newer Android updates, I believe API 26, I could no longer get these updates if the Android device's screen was off. I was trying to think of a way around this and came up with an idea:

What if I paired the Android device and the Bluetooth device - would this allow for the message to be received when the Android screen is off?

Previously, all my BLE devices were part of a mesh, so I would regularly have the Android app check for changes in the mesh and turn the screen on to notify the user if needed. Now, because of the background execution limits introduced, I must require the Android device to have the screen on at all times, which leads to the death of display over time.

I'm not that great at programming in C, which is the language the BLE chips are programmed in, so I wanted to ask this first before spending hours just to see this NOT work. So, just to repeat the question: Will having a BLE device paired with the Android device allow a message through these restrictions when the Android screen is off?

If not - is there a way I can make this work?

Thank you for any info!

Comment: Are you talking about getting "messages" in form of advertisements or GATT notifications?

Comment: Hi @Emil - Currently I have my tablets scanning every 30 seconds, reading both the encrypted Advertising Packet and Scan Response Packet of the nearest BLE security device (by signal strength) and updating the tablet screen depending on what the decrypted data contains. Since I can't do this with the screen off, I was hoping to put a tablet and BLE device in each room, and pair the devices together. When the BLE device is triggered in the room, it would send a GATT notification to the tablet that it is paired with, where the tablet screen would possibly turn on and process data.

Comment: I have noticed that sending a cloud message/push message through Google Firebase can turn a tablet screen on, so I was hoping this could work as well. In all honestly, the better option would be to NOT pair, but just connect to the BLE Service/Characteristic and receive notifications while the tablet screen is off. These are BLE Accelerometer devices, so I just need to send a byte of data to the connected, or paired, device. I figured connecting may not be enough to turn the screen on, but pairing might be. I'm unsure of both scenarios, but obviously connecting without pairing would be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use notifications instead of advertisements. This will deliver data instantly and works even if the screen is off. Newer versions of Android have introduced more restrictions for BLE scanning when the screen is off.
2. Use `connectGatt` with `autoConnect` set to true to automatically connect and reconnect in case the connection drops.
3. Use a Foreground Service in your app process to prevent the app process from being killed. If your app process exits, all Bluetooth connections are dropped as well.
4. You could use CompanionDeviceManager to gain some extra permissions.

You don't really need to be paired but it has some benefits such as faster connection setup and correctly remembering the address type (flaw in the API that this is missing).

Comment: Thank you for your answer Emil, the autoConnect was something I was unaware of, but extremely crucial for what I'm doing. I do have a foreground service running, so that's taken care of. I was thinking of making my own pairing process through the app to remember the connection to that specific devices during my application set up, which I'll do in the field, so that isn't a big issue. However, I'm wondering what you would recommend using CompanionDeviceManager for - association, possibly? I looked over the class and it looks very helpful. Just wondering your take on this. Thanks!

Comment: First the CompanionDeviceManager can be used as a helper utility so that you don't need to program the pairing process. Other than that, you get some special permissions in your app. I think it's a bit unclear exactly what you get, but I've done my best to describe it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71294645/556495.